# Heroku - Rails -We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I have recently deployed my first Rails App to Heroku however I am having some issues. All of the pages within my app work, home, logging in etc. The issue lies when you create an article, the second you click create "We're sorry, but something went wrong." and I am not too sure what the cause of this is.

My log is below (went for a large log incase its a more in depth issue), any assistance would be great

edit1: It works perfectly fine locally, just not when hosted on Heroku.

```
 2015-03-03T19:14:02.209685+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148070+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-03 19:14:03] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148087+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148092+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148083+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148094+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148081+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148084+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148089+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:35:in `run'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148090+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148095+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148098+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148102+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148104+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148097+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148100+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148107+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148108+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148109+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148105+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148113+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148111+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148114+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148115+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148117+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148118+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148120+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:3:in `load'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148121+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148130+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-03 19:14:03] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2015-03-03T19:14:03.378049+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:26789
2015-03-03T19:14:03.378051+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-03-03T19:14:03.378053+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-03-03T19:14:03.378054+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-03-03T19:14:03.378042+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-03-03T19:14:03.148131+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-03 19:14:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2015-03-03T19:14:03.884727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 15184 -e production`
2015-03-03T19:14:04.775635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-03-03T19:14:05.874118+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
2015-03-03T19:14:09.629948+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-03 19:14:09] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2015-03-03T19:14:09.630305+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-03 19:14:09] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=15184
2015-03-03T19:14:09.629959+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-03-03 19:14:09] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
2015-03-03T19:14:09.787044+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-03-03T19:14:26.573786+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=ecc8fd96-00f1-4435-9703-b1efac3fed28 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=213ms status=200 bytes=5381
2015-03-03T19:14:26.701195+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-6049aa67652f09bdadb57b1d4a3eb671.css" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=48854a7c-607e-4e93-b098-01055ddc83ee fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=204
2015-03-03T19:14:26.711313+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1354e829e4b3cf2f1cc658732c994fd9.js" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=57752080-1301-4f14-947e-2ce90eda1193 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=218
2015-03-03T19:14:26.713237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/images/thumb/missing.png" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=87a44d99-7b84-4abd-959c-498ce712b7e7 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=1829
2015-03-03T19:14:31.321548+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/articles/1" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=2f475337-d1e9-41b3-a63b-c491c59c73dc fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=49ms status=302 bytes=1192
2015-03-03T19:14:31.453965+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=3fa4056d-9dc2-44bb-9852-42bce2bf7d7d fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=27ms status=200 bytes=5223
2015-03-03T19:14:34.368597+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/new" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=d909c9bc-1a26-4080-83a2-8c9f9ba5dae8 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=92ms status=200 bytes=5685
2015-03-03T19:15:41.009845+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=8aacde4c-9526-42ce-a79f-ecbfd1b7e10b fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=292ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-03T19:15:41.147654+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=97875c8f-a97e-4de3-8b00-e3e72c054d70 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=228
2015-03-03T19:23:41.180767+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by a.fenwick2608@gmail.com
2015-03-03T19:23:47.329479+00:00 heroku[run.2590]: Awaiting client
2015-03-03T19:23:47.370495+00:00 heroku[run.2590]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-03-03T19:23:47.673617+00:00 heroku[run.2590]: State changed from starting to up
2015-03-03T19:23:54.603079+00:00 heroku[run.2590]: Process exited with status 0
2015-03-03T19:23:54.635002+00:00 heroku[run.2590]: State changed from up to complete
2015-03-03T19:24:02.474641+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=de91fb7d-0a16-45fa-ae0b-6d6833a10196 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=4793
2015-03-03T19:24:02.619220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-6049aa67652f09bdadb57b1d4a3eb671.css" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=ff8032c1-fee8-45c4-98a7-93b5211f2a22 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=204
2015-03-03T19:24:02.621947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1354e829e4b3cf2f1cc658732c994fd9.js" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=02db900c-f403-4570-950c-dea92fe947c7 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=218
2015-03-03T19:24:06.219696+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/new" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=7ecbba6b-43cd-403a-a27d-d960f92139a4 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=54ms status=200 bytes=5685
2015-03-03T19:24:07.645077+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_in" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=78238da8-7879-42d9-9dce-02cf1e20df5e fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=38ms status=302 bytes=1245
2015-03-03T19:24:07.772265+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=affa34b7-3bfa-4ee8-9915-f4b50e1f2be9 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=200 bytes=5159
2015-03-03T19:24:09.948379+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/new" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=d67c6b43-d66e-413a-910a-d75f7bf74f8e fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=5685
2015-03-03T19:24:17.727992+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=caf329b8-186b-4b70-b8da-aa751f92ad8d fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=315ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-03T19:24:17.875069+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=ed0ae4cc-97ca-4b1f-b5dc-d9e862f1c0eb fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-03-03T19:24:30.018723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=bc6f791e-867c-45dd-b750-48b80c7f0898 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-03T19:25:21.138186+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=4e97e426-2503-4833-9014-482e5f26c680 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=21ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-03T19:25:28.299524+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=7bd5eefe-a097-4cbf-8808-cddae9162069 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=376ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-03T19:25:28.438774+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=7e9a1b4c-9682-48c8-b3e5-3a91d28c9612 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-03-03T19:25:32.161534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_out" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=32e40e91-7567-4edf-bb58-98fb0c59ee77 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=33ms status=302 bytes=940
2015-03-03T19:25:32.334657+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=bf226ff8-99df-4d24-a67d-2e9d5f4e1d41 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=60ms status=200 bytes=5057
2015-03-03T19:25:36.137296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/new" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=0ecbaab0-64ad-411f-934c-994568b8b07c fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=24ms status=302 bytes=1127
2015-03-03T19:25:36.287640+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_in" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=b28cf026-413e-47c1-ba69-36cb70bfc3af fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=46ms status=200 bytes=5891
2015-03-03T19:28:12.343547+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=028fd539-4f74-4d22-b062-401ce2c21ce2 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=4731
2015-03-03T19:28:17.707271+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/new" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=d0150a73-7064-4645-b88e-205cb10f42a6 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=12ms status=302 bytes=1127
2015-03-03T19:28:17.843085+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_in" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=8fa7d5f5-3674-496e-ba01-40d3e2e95e52 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30ms status=200 bytes=5891
2015-03-03T19:28:22.595846+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_in" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=1fce26e5-2ac5-4416-8fd6-8fc34a1b481f fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=130ms status=302 bytes=1074
2015-03-03T19:28:22.721401+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/new" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=58c16b64-9fca-4d3c-b869-9dfd1dfbc0cf fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=6071
2015-03-03T19:28:32.119343+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=d200aef8-e6d6-4bdb-953d-d84ab806b3df fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=305ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-03T19:28:32.269683+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=d66abb7f-82de-4086-b24d-a8837b74d408 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-03-03T19:28:37.076820+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=92f55ab0-2a24-4b9e-afab-20327d760f62 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=34ms status=200 bytes=4793
2015-03-03T19:29:03.313220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/1" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=f795c912-3d6c-48b6-b9e3-f552464c5462 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=17ms status=404 bytes=1829
2015-03-03T19:29:25.556951+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by a.fenwick2608@gmail.com
2015-03-03T19:29:43.841688+00:00 heroku[run.7507]: Awaiting client
2015-03-03T19:29:43.874382+00:00 heroku[run.7507]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-03-03T19:29:44.261375+00:00 heroku[run.7507]: State changed from starting to up
2015-03-03T19:29:51.271792+00:00 heroku[run.7507]: Process exited with status 0
2015-03-03T19:29:51.287247+00:00 heroku[run.7507]: State changed from up to complete
2015-03-03T19:30:03.041396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=49df8661-7e3e-4ac7-a54c-f09747e983f9 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=4793
2015-03-03T19:30:04.857386+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/new" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=f9520828-eab8-404b-97c9-30b9a23a8a98 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=37ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=5685
2015-03-03T19:30:11.368664+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=ff0900cb-eb19-44bb-8fea-6b2a93431ac8 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=366ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-03-03T19:30:11.509744+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
 path="/favicon.ico" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=ad8abd27-1d1a-442b-bddb-5809657b4a67 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-03-03T19:30:44.141535+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=776f4b12-9e6d-4b83-b2e1-ce4d5b8380e9 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=4793
2015-03-03T19:30:44.331447+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1354e829e4b3cf2f1cc658732c994fd9.js" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=be5414f2-9035-4c2f-bf1a-b8db2ac0f461 fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=218
2015-03-03T19:30:44.273171+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-6049aa67652f09bdadb57b1d4a3eb671.css" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=b4e45e47-8747-48a7-ab6d-fae59ad6778e fwd="82.39.170.74" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=204
2015-03-03T19:30:48.221760+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=92614011-0cea-492c-b3ab-194c4a076151 fwd="31.13.110.117" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=4681
2015-03-03T19:30:50.614105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=e334f7ac-9d72-4550-b139-7a91f7b17ed6 fwd="31.13.100.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=4681
2015-03-03T19:30:53.938089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/articles/new" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=ff901ec8-247e-453c-99c8-a3eabdcdea37 fwd="2.99.81.240" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=302 bytes=1127
2015-03-03T19:30:54.102681+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-6049aa67652f09bdadb57b1d4a3eb671.css" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=0251f441-a23a-43fb-91ae-df6b30711844 fwd="2.99.81.240" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=204
2015-03-03T19:30:54.232303+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1354e829e4b3cf2f1cc658732c994fd9.js" host=fierce-hamlet-6237.herokuapp.com request_id=31c4c036-771c-4aec-a869-b7986f428903 fwd="2.99.81.240" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=218
```

Answer (score 7):

in config/environments/production.rb (or whatever environment your app is running in) set temporary `config.consider_all_requests_local = true`, deploy it and you should be able to see exact error message instead of "We're sorry..." after you add the article. Most likely you forgot to add something to production configuration, like host name.

Comment: I am too too sure what the issue was, but I changed that and somehow it now works. Migrated the db etc before, but this time it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

or

```
heroku run rake db:miragte
```